# ExpressJS: 404 error webpack-dev-middleware

Tags: node.js, express, webpack-dev-middleware

Recently I faced a following issue: I'm using expressJS framework for some backend stuff and webpack-dev-middleware for compiling assets during development, seems that dev-middleware is doing its stuff - compiling css and js, because I see some green messages on terminal, but I am constantly geting 404 error when I try to access my js or css file - /css/app.css - 404,  /js/app.js - 404 etc. When I try to compile assets using webpack all works fine and I get compiled css and js files with no problems. There is github repo [here](https://github.com/barryqt2019/test_repo)

**app.js**

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const argv = require('yargs').argv;

const app = express();

const devMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackConfig = require('../../webpack.config');
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig(null, { mode: 'development' }));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index', { title: "home" });
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../public')));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

if (argv.mode !== 'production') {
  app.use(devMiddleware(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig(null, { mode: 'development' }).output.publicPath
  }));

  app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler));
}

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const Path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  return {
    entry: {
      app: [
        "./src/client/app.js",
        "./src/scss/style.scss",
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://localhost/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000'
      ]
    },
    output: {
      filename: 'js/[name].js',
      path: Path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
      publicPath: '/'
    },
    mode: argv.mode || 'development',
    devtool: argv.mode !== 'production' ? 'source-map' : false,
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new TerserJSPlugin({ sourceMap: true }),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
          cssProcessorOptions: {

            map: argv.mode !== 'production' ? {
              inline: false // set to false if you want CSS source maps
            } : null
          }
        })],
    },
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
        // both options are optional
        filename: 'css/[name].css',
        chunkFilename: '[id].css',
      }),
      new CopyPlugin([
        { from: 'images/*' }
      ]),
      // OccurrenceOrderPlugin is needed for webpack 1.x only
      new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      // Use NoErrorsPlugin for webpack 1.x
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "babel-loader",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          exclude: [Path.resolve("/node_modules/")],
          use: [
            {
              loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              options: {
                // you can specify a publicPath here
                // by default it uses publicPath in webpackOptions.output
                publicPath: '../',
                hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
              },
            }, {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                url: false,
              }

            }, {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }, {
              loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                includePaths: [Path.resolve('src/scss')],
              }
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: should the output dir be public/<dir>? ` output: { filename: 'js/[name].js', `

Comment: @GrafiCode, output dir seems fine it uses public folder . Btw I fixed this issue by adding  write-file-webpack-plugin that forces middleware to compile assets into files, but it looks hacky, because it should serve file from memory like webpack dev server does